# App store upload fails, even though bundle identifier is correct

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have a project for which I get:
"App Store Connect Operation Error"
"No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'XXX.XXX-XXX' is correct."

However, the store listing exists and if my coworker does the upload it works fine.
We have no idea how to get it to work from my computer. Other projects seems to work fine.

Additional information:

1. So far the store listing exists, but only available on test flight.
2. We have tried upgrading my XCode to be the same version as my coworker's.
3. We have tried editing my account details in my xcode. We gave up on that and then added my coworker's account details as well (weird, I know, but we are getting desperate).
4. I havent made a change to the project, I simply download and archive + upload and then i get this error.

Please, any hints or ideas would be great!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turns out the problem was that one of the accounts (under XCode > Preferences > Accounts), did not have permissions to this particular app. What is weird, though, is that the four other accounts here DID have access permissions to this app. We aren't sure how XCode decides which account to try and use - but after giving that particular account the correct permissions, everything worked fine.

Will investigate more and maybe update this answer in the future - but, there you have it. Maybe it helps someone else in the future.